How to stream shell script output in real-time using Bun, Hono?
I'm trying to create a real-time streaming output of a shell script execution using Bun and Hono. Currently, the output is buffered and only shows up all at once when the script finishes, but I need it to stream in real-time as the script produces output.
Shell Script (deploy-container.sh):
#!/bin/bash
# Script that deploys a container and shows progress
echo " Starting deployment process..."
echo "  → Deploying Docker container..."
# ... more echo statements and actual deployment logic
echo "✅ Deployed successfully!"

Current Implementation:
(deploy.ts):
import { $ } from "bun";

export const runDeployment = async (
  imageName: string,
  subDomain: string,
  port: number
) => {
  try {
    const res =
      await $`echo ${process.env.SYSTEM_PASSWORD} | sudo -S deploy-container.sh ${imageName} ${subDomain} ${port}`;

    return res.stdout.toString();
  } catch (e) {
    console.error("Error running deployment:", e);
    throw {
      success: false,
      error: e,
    };
  }
};

(index.ts):
import { stream } from "hono/streaming";
import { runDeployment } from "../lib/deploy";

app.post("/deployContainer/:repoName", async (c) => {
  try {
    const repoName = c.req.param("repoName");
    const imageName = `${repoName}:latest`;

    const port = generateRandomPort();
    const subDomain = generateSubdomain(repoName);
    const deployData = runDeployment(imageName, subDomain, port);
    return stream(c, async (clientStream) => {
      const heartbeat = setInterval(async () => {
        try {
          await clientStream.write(" ");
        } catch (err) {
          console.error("Heartbeat failed:", err);
        }
      }, 1000);

      try {
        const res = await deployData;
        clientStream.writeln(res);
      } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error deploying container:", error);
        clientStream.write(`Error deploying container: ${error}\n`);
      } finally {
        clearInterval(heartbeat);
      }
    });
  } catch (e) {
    console.error(e);
    return c.json({ success: false, error: e }, 500);
  }
});


Current Behavior:

The script executes successfully
Output is collected but only shown all at once when the script completes
No real-time streaming of the output

Expected Behavior:

Each line of output should appear in real-time as the script produces it
Similar to watching the output in a terminal

Any help would be appreciated in getting the output to stream in real-time rather than being buffered until the end.

Won't the await $`...`; only return the output when the shell command completes?

sudo -S stdbuf -oL deploy-container.sh ... but that await situation still blocks it

@Fravadona I'v tried without it but still the same problem

Did you try spawning the process? https://stackoverflow.com/a/64058100/3387716

@Fravadona Tried it, I can see the whats happening in the console each step can see it, but in postman for example the response is not being updated in the real time but being send once at the end.

each program have their buffers
